# How to find() by level in mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, find

How can I find one object of "data" by _id ("_id":"ABC")?

```
  [
    {
      "_id": "123",
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "my name 1",
          "_id": "abc"
        },
        {
          "name": "my name 2",
          "_id": "def"
        },
        ...
       ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "567",
      .....
    }    
  ]
```

I want to get one object of "data" [object,object...] when every object has _id too.

```
const result = myModel.find({any}) 
result = { "name":"my name 1",
           "_id":"abc"
         }
```

Comment: Did you try `result.data.id('abc')`?

Comment: The idea is to search by id (sub _id)  I want to find 'abc' or 'def' by _id